# Getting attribute from xml node

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I have created an xml for a flash player configuration.  I am trying to load attributes of each node into a textbox or dropdownlist.

```
<config>
  <param name="width" value="960" />
  <param name="height" value="545" />
  <param name="loop" value="0" />
  <param name="autoload" value="1" />
  <param name="autoplay" value="1" />
  <param name="showstop" value="1" />
</config>

Dim XmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument

    XmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("config.xml"))

    For Each Attribute As XmlAttribute In XmlDoc.DocumentElement.Attributes
        If Attribute.Name = "width" Then
            If Attribute.Name = "value' then" Then
                tbxWidth.Text = Attribute.Value
            End If

        End If


    Next
```

Can someone help with this?

Comment: Config has no attributes it has nodes, they have attributes... You can do this with XmlDoc.DocumentElement.Select("param[@name='width']). if that's not null then get the value atrribute.

Comment: On top of that how can attribute have two names...

Answer (score 0):

Keeping with the way you started...

```
Dim XmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
XmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("config.xml"))

For Each node As XmlNode In XmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("param[@name='width']")
    XmlAttribute Attribute = node.Attributes["value"]        
    If Attribute IsNot Nothing Then
            tbxWidth.Text = Attribute.value
    End If
  Next
Next
```

Not a VB boy, so expect the odd silly...

Note if you had more than one param nodes with a width attribute, this will take the last...

Comment: with this approach I would have to cut and paste the code over 12-15 times and change the ("param[@name='width']") with the next value and textbox.  Is there a way I can do this without having to cut and paste it so many times?

Comment: Really? And how were you going to map an attribute to a particular textbox? Just Do SelectNodes("param") instead. From there you'll have to get the name AND value attributes and use name (switch statement?, Dictionary<String,TextBox> ? ) to figure out which textBox you are going to set the value of. We can only answer the questions you ask...

Comment: If I were doing this, I'd have this method return a dictionary of name and value, probably with one Linq statement, and then deal with how to display them in the form.

Comment: I'm not sure how to return a dictionary.  Can you give me an example?

Comment: Only in C#, I'm not a VB Boy. Ask another question. Give your example xml and ask how to return a Dictionary of name and value from the params nodes from it with Linq to xml